# Accessing capture group in preg_replace_callback

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a string that I’m going to be replacing parts of. However, I’d like to use only a part of the pattern that I’m matching.

Example:

```
$subject = "methodName(127)";

$callback = function($match)
{
    echo $match[0];
    // will echo 'methodName(127)'

    return;
}

preg_replace_callback('/[a-z]+\([0-9]+\)/', $callback, $subject, 1);
```

In this example, my callback method will get access to the entire pattern match. However, I’d like to isolate just the numbers between the parentheses.  A capture group would seemingly be useful here, but I don’t know if there’s a way to gain access to it within `$callback` or perhaps pass it as an argument (such as `use ($arg)`).

I do understand that I can simply `preg_match` the pattern between parentheses in `$callback`, but I wonder if that’s possible to do with capture groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use capturing groups for accessing the numbers. This seems to do what you want -

```
$subject = "methodName(127)";
$callback = function($match)
{
    var_dump($match);
    /*
        OUTPUT-
        array
          0 => string 'methodName(127)' (length=15)
          1 => string '127' (length=3)
    */
    echo $match[1];
    //OUTPUT - > 127
    return;
};
preg_replace_callback('/[a-zA-Z]+\(([0-9]+)\)/', $callback, $subject, 1);
//                                 ^      ^ Capturing groups
```